# check in which range a number falls and return a new column with corresponding shift

Tags: r, data.table, iranges

I have two data frames ch and shift. In data frame ch i have a column with name pos which contains numbers as shown below.
In data frame shift i have three columns with name shft, start and end.

```
ch <- structure(list(pos = c(3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25, 
6.75, 7.25, 7.75, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 
4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25, 6.75, 7.25, 7.75, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 
1.75, 2.25)), .Names = "pos", row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")

head(ch)
   pos
1 3.25
2 3.75
3 4.25
4 4.75
5 5.25
6 5.75

shift <- structure(list(shift = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D"), class = "factor"), start = c(0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 
1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25, 6.75, 
7.25, 7.75), end = c(0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 
3.75, 4.25, 4.75, 5.25, 5.75, 6.25, 6.75, 7.25, 7.75, 8)), .Names = c("shft", 
"start", "end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
))
```

head(shift)

```
   shft  start end
1     B  0.00 0.25
2     C  0.25 0.75
3     B  0.75 1.25
4     D  1.25 1.75
5     C  1.75 2.25
6     D  2.25 2.75
```

I want to check the each number from pos column in ch dataframe with the range listed in start and end columns of shift data frame and the respective shft such as A,B,C,D has to be assigned in a column with a name shift.

the comparison has to be like `>= start and < end`.

by looking at a question at stackoverflow i found a solution but it's working like in which range the value will fall

```
library(data.table)
T1 <- data.table(ch)
T2 <- data.table(shift)
setkey(T2, start, end)
T1[, c("start", "end") := pos] 
foverlaps(T1, T2)
```

with the above command line, the result is like for 0.25 i will get a row with shift B and one row with shift c. in my dataframe ch i have 31 rows and after excuting above scripts in the result i have 62 rows.

can some tell me how can i perform the comparison`(>= start and < end)` not just falling the range. data frame ch in reality will be having numbers not only what i have shown like 0.25, 3.25, 7.25 but also 3.14, 0.89,7.25,6.93,5,46.

Answer (score 1):

Given that all of your partitions overlap:
EDIT: I realize now you wanted >= start, rather than <= end, which is an easy fix, cut takes `right = FALSE`

base R:

```
ch$shift <- cut(ch$pos,breaks = c(0,shift$end),labels = shift$shft, right = FALSE)
```

with dplyr:

```
ch <- ch %>% mutate(shift = cut(pos,breaks = c(0,shift$end),labels = shift$shft, right = FALSE))
```

Comment: i tried with data.table it shows the below error:: Error in shift$end : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: using baseR::instead of showing A,B,C,D.  it showing like this                   [1] (2.75,3.25] (3.25,3.75] (3.75,4.25] (4.25,4.75] (4.75,5.25] (5.25,5.75] (5.75,6.25] (6.25,6.75] (6.75,7.25] (7.25,7.75] [0,0.25]   
[12] (0.25,0.75] (0.75,1.25] (1.25,1.75] (1.75,2.25] (2.25,2.75] (2.75,3.25] (3.25,3.75] (3.75,4.25] (4.25,4.75] (4.75,5.25] (5.25,5.75]
[23] (5.75,6.25] (6.25,6.75] (6.75,7.25] (7.25,7.75] [0,0.25]    (0.25,0.75] (0.75,1.25] (1.25,1.75] (1.75,2.25]
17 Levels: [0,0.25] (0.25,0.75] (0.75,1.25] (1.25,1.75] (1.75,2.25] (2.25,2.75] (2.75,3.25] (3.25,3.75] (3.75,4.25] ... (7.75,8]

Comment: removed the data.table one until I fix it, the first one will work fine in a data.table though

Comment: Not getting that error, the base R just runs for me fine

Comment: in baseR, it not showing any error. instead of showing the labels A,B,C or D it giving the range in new column as shown above

Comment: with dplyr option:: i got the following error...                                                 Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97021/discussion-between-shape-and-chanti).

Comment: no error with the new dplyr code...but the output is like what i have shown below...... pos       shift
1  3.25 (2.75,3.25]
2  3.75 (3.25,3.75]
3  4.25 (3.75,4.25]